# NOT Equal(<>) in Oracle SQL is ignoring Index and NULL valued rows

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sql-execution-plan, sqlperformance

I have one query where need to filter based on NOT Equal values in Oracle SQL. Can not use EQUAL to condition as the possible values fo the column in unknown.

Query:

```
SELECT * from employee where name <> 'John';
```

The above query is ignoring the index in name column as well as rows having null in name column is not returned.

Solution Tried for NULL safe return.

```
SELECT * from employee where name is null OR name <> 'John';

SELECT * from employee where nvl(name, 'NOT John') <> 'John';
```

The above two queries is able to filter out the null rows.
But not able to use the index defined in name column.

Please advise.

Comment: If optimizer *thinks* that full table scan is more optimal than using index, it'll do so. Why do you think that index **must** be used? Your "job" is to create index (if appropriate) and regularly gather statistics; Oracle will do the rest, and in vast majority of cases it'll do it right.

Comment: Yes right. But its better if the explain plain says it is using the index defined. In that case we know for use it will not do the full table scan will use the B+ Tree for query

Comment: If the optimizer thinks that using the index is better, it will do so and tell in the execution plan. If it does decide on a full table scan, it will tell you so. And as others said, just why do you think that using the index is better?

Comment: Generally *not equal* means *everything in the entire Universe except this one*, especially assuming semantics of `name` column. Index is not fast=true switch, it doesn't speed the query up just because it's named index. You may read about access paths and physical storage in the [Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-4B6624DA-92BA-48C2-B045-D8B71046E81B) that briefly describes access strategies and has links to the SQL tuning guide.

Answer (score 2):

Intention of an index is to find quickly a specific value. Conditions on "not equal" typically do not gain by an index. `NULL` values are not indexed, so there is no benefit either.

It looks different if you use a `BITMAP INDEX`, there the index would be used. However, BITMAP indexes have other limitations, it depends on your application and data whether it could be useful or not.

Comment: Right. Is there any alternate syntax or hints that can be used to achieve the same NOT equal functionality that uses the defined Index

Comment: As stated in comment by @Littlefoot, why do you think the query runs faster when the index is used? In some conditions a FULL TABLE SCAN is faster than an index scan - and your query is a typical example of such condition.